# Proof verification: show $f(z)$ is constant on its domain

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Could anyone help me verify my proof and see if there is any step that does not make sense? Thank you very much.

> Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Show that if
>   \begin{equation}
> \left| f(z) \right| \le \sqrt{\left| z \right| } + \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \left| z \right|}} \text{ for all } z\ne 0
> \end{equation}
>   then $f(z)$ is a constant function.

First, notice that $\lim_{z\to 0} z f(z) = 0$. This is because
\begin{equation}
\left| z f(z) \right| \le \left| z \right| \sqrt{\left| z \right|} + \frac{\left|z\right|}{\sqrt{\left| z\right|}}
\end{equation}
In addition, $f(z)$ is analytic on a punctured disk around zero. Thus, by Riemann’s removable singularity theorem, $f(z)$ has an analytic extension $g(z)$ defined as
\begin{equation}
g(z) =\displaystyle
\begin{cases}
f(z) &\text{if } z\ne 0 \\
\lim_{z\to 0} f(z) &\text{if } z = 0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We now prove that $g'(z)=0$ whenever $z \ne 0$. This will imply that $f(z)$ is constant. By Cauchy's integral formula, we have
\begin{equation}
g'(z_0) = f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} dz
\end{equation}
,where $C_R$ is the circle of radius $R$ enclosing $z_0$. We have the following estimate:
\begin{equation}
\left| f'(z_0) \right| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \left| \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} \right| dz
\end{equation}
Notice that since $z_0$ is already chosen, we can choose $R$ to be big. This enables us to conclude that
\begin{equation}
\left| (z - z_0)^2 \right| \ge \big| \left| z \right| - \left| z_0 \right| \big|^2 = (R - \left| z_0 \right|)^2 > R^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\left| f(z) \right| \le \sqrt{R} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}
\end{equation}
This gives us
\begin{equation}
\left| g'(z_0)\right| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{R} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}}{R^2} \int_{C_R} 1 dz = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{R+1}{R^2\sqrt{R}} 2\pi R = \frac{R+1}{R\sqrt{R}} \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } R \longrightarrow \infty
\end{equation}
This shows that $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. So $f(z)$ is a constant over its domain.

Comment: You proved that $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $zf(z)$, but how do you make an extension of $f(z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach: Write $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$ Using the hypothesis along with the orthogonality of the exponentials, we get

$$2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}= \int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2\, dt \le  2\pi(\sqrt r +1/\sqrt r)^2.$$

The only way this can hold as $r\to \infty$ is for $a_n = 0$ for $n>0.$ Thus $f\equiv a_0,$ a constant as desired.

Answer (score 0):

In your first step:  The Reimann Removable Singularity Theorem says that if $f(z)$ is (1) analytic and (2) **bounded** on a punctured open disk, then: (3) the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches the puncture point exists, and (2)  the function $g(z)$, defined as you have defined it on the whole disk, is analytic.

(See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannRemovableSingularityTheorem.html)

You have quoted a theorem saying that if $f(z)$ is (1) analytic and (3') the limit of $zf(z)$ as $z$ approaches the puncture point exists, then (4) the function $g(z)$, defined as you have defined it on the whole disk, is analytic.  This is not a theorem:  for a counterexample, try $f(z) = \frac1z$.  You have never shown the function is (2) bounded on some disk.

When constructing the proof (after fixing this flaw), you should check, up until the point that you use the given inequality,  that your statements are true for the example $f(z) =  \frac1z$.

---

Then look at the function $f:\Bbb{C}-\{0\}\mapsto \Bbb{C} | f(z) = \sqrt{z} + \frac1{\sqrt{z}}$

This satisfies the inequality and has no other singularity points than at $z=0$, but it does have a branch cut (ending at $z=0$).  It might help you understand why the theorem works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem This version of theorem does not requite $f$ to be bounded... I am confused. Which one is right?

Comment: Also I am confused, because we do **not** have $\lim_{z\to 0} z \frac{1}{z} = 0$?

Comment: Ah, I had the wrong version of the theorem.  I guess Mathworld is not as reliable as I thought.Given the 4-condition equivalence on wikipedia, I think your proof is fine.