# When can $f(z)$ be extended to be analytic on $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is my confusion. I used to thought the following.

> Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on some punctured disk $C_R-\{0\}$. If zero is a removable singularity, then $f(z)$ can be "made" analytic on the whole disk, by redefining $f(0) := \lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$.

For example, $f(z) = \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^2}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, since $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z) = \frac{1}{2}$, by L'Hopital or Laurent series.

Then I thought

> If I can show that $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$ exists, then that means the singularity at zero is removable.

But this entries from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) confuses me:

> Let $D \subset C$ be an open subset of the complex plane, $a\in D$, and $f$ a holomorphic function defined on $D - \{a\}$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $a$.
> 2. $\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)f(z) = 0$

Why do we have $\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)f(z) =0$, **instead of** $\lim_{z\to a} f(z)$ exists? Wouldn't this give us contradictory result?

As a concrete example, considere some $f(z)$ defined on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and satisifes

$$\left| f(z) \right| < \sqrt{\left| z \right|} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left| z \right|}}$$

If we consider $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$, then it doesn't exist. So it shouldn't be extendable. But if we consider $\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z)$, this equal to zero. Thus, as suggested by this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/262005/90914), it is actually extendable.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Holomorphic functions are quite marvellous beasts. In fact, the two conditions are equivalent for holomorphic functions. And for your concrete example, if $f$ is holomorphic, and satisfies these bounds then $f$ is actually constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's actually an exercise problem I've been struggling with today. I've read answers in the link and I could only understand the first one. Right now I want to understand why I get two different conclusions.

Comment: @DanielFischer For one thing, it is clear that $\lim f(z)$ does not exist. But on the other hand, the theorem suggest that since $\lim z f(z)$ exists, it is actually extendable. That confuses me

Comment: No, it's not at all clear that the limit doesn't exist. What is clear is that the inequalities _alone_ are not sufficient to guarantee the existence of the limit. But the inequalities together with the fact that $f$ is holomorphic on some set $\{ z : 0 < \lvert z\rvert < r\}$ suffice to guarantee the existence of the limit. Being holomorphic is a really really **really** strong condition with fantastic consequences.

Comment: @DanielFischer $\lim_{z\to 0} \sqrt{|z|} + 1/\sqrt{|z|} \to \infty$ doesn't say anything about $\lim f(z)$. True. I made a silly mistake. As for the example, itself, is $f$ extendable? According to Wiki, it is. But another version requires that $f$ be bounded on the punctured disk, which isn't clear to me: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannRemovableSingularityTheorem.html

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree with Misakov that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) is confusing. I think it would be clearer to start with "by the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic theorem, a non-trivial result is that a holomorphic function with a (non removable) isolated singularity cannot be bounded around it, because otherwise $(z-a)^2 f(z)$ is holomorphic so that $f(z)$ had a pole of order at most $2$, but since $f(z)$ is bounded the order is $0$, i.e. $f(z)$ was holomorphic".

Comment: @user1952009 Uh, funny question... I always thought that holomorphic and analytic is the same thing?

Comment: @Misakov not at all ! $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ means that it is **complex differentiable** at every $z \in U$ (so that $f'(z)$ is well-defined). Then you prove the Cauchy integral theorem and formula which gives a Taylor series for $f(z)$ on every disk $\subset U$, proving that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic (the converse being obvious).

Comment: @Misakov Yes and no. By definition, a function is analytic if it can be represented by a power series around each point, and a function is holomorphic if it is complex differentiable at all points of its (open) domain. So the definitions are different, and it's a not entirely obvious theorem, that the two are equivalent.

Comment: For example $f(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x}dx$, it not obvious at all that it is analytic on $Re(z) > 0$, whereas it is obvious that it is holomorphic (since $f'(z) =  \int_0^\infty \ln(z) x^{z-1} e^{-x}dx$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holomorphic functions have quite a lot of rigidity. In particular, holomorphic functions cannot have arbitrary growth behaviour at an isolated singularity.

Let $f$ be holomorphic on a punctured disk $\{ z : 0 < \lvert z-a\rvert < R\}$. Consider the following conditions on $f$:

1. $f$ has a holomorphic extension to the disk $\{ z : \lvert z-a\rvert < R\}$.
2. $\lim\limits_{z \to a} f(z)$ exists (in $\mathbb{C}$).
3. There is an $r \in (0,R]$ such that $f$ is bounded on $\{ z : 0 < \lvert z-a\rvert < r\}$.
4. $\lim\limits_{z\to a}\: (z - a) f(z) = 0$.

Then it is almost trivial to see that each condition implies the following condition(s). But for holomorphic $f$, the weakest of these conditions is strong enough to imply the strongest. Let us prove that.

So assume $(z - a)f(z) \to 0$ as $z\to a$, and consider the function

$$F \colon z \mapsto \begin{cases}(z - a)^2 f(z) &, z \neq a \\ \qquad 0 &, z = a.\end{cases}$$

On the punctured disk, $F$ is the product of two holomorphic functions, and therefore holomorphic. Since already $(z-a)\cdot f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to a$, $F$ is clearly continuous at $a$. And

$$\lim_{z\to a} \frac{F(z) - F(a)}{z - a} = \lim_{z\to a} \frac{(z-a)^2 f(z)}{z-a} = \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)f(z) = 0,$$

so $F$ is complex differentiable at $a$ too, with $F'(a) = 0$. This means $F$ is holomorphic on the full disk $\{ z : \lvert z-a\rvert < R\}$. Therefore, $F$ has a power series expansion about $a$,

$$F(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n.$$

In this power series expansion, we have $a_n = \frac{1}{n!} F^{(n)}(a)$, and we saw that $F(a) = F'(a) = 0$, so in fact

$$F(z) = \sum_{n = 2}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n = (z-a)^2 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_{n+2}(z-a)^n,$$ and therefore

$$f(z) = \frac{F(z)}{(z-a)^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_{n+2}(z-a)^n\tag{$\ast$}$$

for $0 < \lvert z-a\rvert < R$.

But the right hand side of $(\ast)$ clearly defines a holomorphic function on the full disk $\{ z : \lvert z-a\rvert < R\}$, and thus yields the desired holomorphic extension of $f$.

Although for the holomorphic extensibility of $f$ the boundedness near $a$, and the existence of $\lim\limits_{z\to a} f(z)$ are clearly necessary, a formally weaker condition is in fact sufficient. Such is the power of complex analyticity.

Comment: Having seen the proof, now I am convinced. For the $f(z)$ in the example though, how did you tell that it is a constant so quickly (if that's the case)? I came up with this proof but it's somewhat long: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006981/proof-verification-show-fz-is-constant-on-its-domain/2007041#2007041 and I don't intuitively see why it _has_ to be constant...

Comment: told you, only the proof explains the theorem correctly :)

Comment: @Misakov Since the growth of $f$ near $0$ is slower than that of $1/z$, it follows that $0$ is a removable singularity. Since the growth near $\infty$ is slower than that of $z$, it follows that $\infty$ is a removable singularity. Thus $f$ is a bounded entire function.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think $\infty$ is a removable singularity + holomorphic on the whole plane is sufficient, no?

Comment: @Misakov Yes. But how do you justify the conclusion in that situation? One can for example say that then $f$ is (extensible to) a holomorphic function on the whole Riemann sphere, and hence $f(\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\})$ is compact, so bounded. One can say that since $\infty$ is a removable singularity, $f$ is bounded on some $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert > R\}$, and by continuity it's bounded on the compact $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$, so bounded on all of $\mathbb{C}$. One can give the argument in other shapes. Or one can leave out the argument because one assumes that the audience knows

Comment: the argument anyway, without it even being hinted at. I'm not comfortable with the last strategy, unless I know my audience very well, so I gave a short sketch.